# jquery mobile not loading in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am attempting to learn how to use jQuery mobile and phonegap together. I have the following basic index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.css" />


        <title>UIAdv</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Welcome to UIAdv</h1>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Anchor</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In there I have the following line which is supposed to render a button using jquery library:

```
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Do Something</a>
```

When the application is run using phonegap run ios and build is successful, I get the attached image output:

[image]

Whereas the button should look like this:

[image]

When I open the index.html in a browser (inside the directory of phonegap app), I get the following in console:

[image]

And I am guessing this is causing the problem. I need your support to solve this first-encounter problem (to myself). I downloaded all jQuery mobile zip file and placed all files within in respective folders in the phonegap app.

Thanks,

Comment: Add `ui-btn-a` or `ui-btn-b` to anchor.

Comment: Also, where is jquery-core?

Comment: Your missing the jQuery reference. Add jQuery right before the JQM reference and that should resolve the uncaught typeerror

Answer (score 1):

The `cordova.js` script tag should be in the header. Also you need to check that the `cordova.js` file is present in the `www` directory of the app. I have rewritten the html file. You can use the code below to test your jquery mobile app. Happy coding!!!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>UIAdv</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" /-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
    <!-- script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script -->
    <!-- script type="text/javascript"> app.initialize(); </script -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="app">
    <h1>Welcome to UIAdv</h1>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Anchor</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```